# how to alter block subject html tag?

Tags: 7, theming, hooks, blocks, javascript

I am trying to change the `<h2>` tags that `block.tpl.php` uses to wrap `<?php print $block->subject ?>` to `<h3>` tags so that I can target them with jQuery UI Accordion. I've got the following code:

```
<?php
    function MYTHEME_block_view_alter(&$data, $block) {
        if($block->module == 'block' && $block->region == 'sidebar') {
            $data['subject']['#tag'] = 'h3';
        }
    }
?>
```

This doesn't work...I assume I'm screwing up the reference to the render element. Does `$data['subject']` contain an array where the HTML tag is stored? What is the correct way to target it?

Alternatively, should I look for a way to re-write block markup so that, in the `sidebar` region, it renders only the `<h3>` and `<div>` required by jQuery UI Accordion? Unless there's a fantastic module for turning blocks into Accordion-ready HTML already out there, I'd rather not install another module.

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the block template for a particular block and can modify the html for block subject.

You can check [theme suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089656) for more reference.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, but I had hoped I wouldn't need to override `block.tpl.php` just for blocks in that region. I got rid of the wrapper `<div>` around each block so that jQuery UI Accordion would get the HTML structure it expects, and I moved the block attributes and classes to the `<h3>` that used to replace the default `<h2>` hardcoded in `block.tpl.php`.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the block output using HOOK_BLOCK_VIEW_ALTER